# strange unexpected token that does not exist

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ps4xs60x/10/) that I am trying to append some rows into a table. This is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.btn-primary', function(){
        $('.table tbody').append('<tr class="child"><td>one</td><td><button id="re" onClick="ae(this.id); function ae(clicked_id) {var items = []; items.push(clicked_id);localStorage.setItem("item",JSON.stringify(items));alert(localStorage.getItem("item",JSON.stringify(items)));}" type="button" class="invite ">Invite</button></td></tr>');
    });
});
```

I can generate the rows but I keep getting an error saying that I have a brace that does not belong there. The problem is the brace is not even there.

> VM140:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Don't ask why I have an `onclick` as an event handler when there is jQuery. I have my reasons for the example. Why am I getting this error?.

Comment: Aside from the error you should really look at using a delegated event handler. Stuffing an entire function in to an outdated `onclick` attribute is a really bad way of doing things

Comment: I have my reasons for stuffing it like that. I am between a rock and hard place and this is the only working way to fix my current problem.

Comment: I'm sure you have lots of reasons, but I'm also sure there's better methods.

Comment: Wow, now that's what they call unmaintainable

Comment: Probably but in my case i assure there is none.

Comment: Fair enough. In that case I will wish you good luck in solving your problem. Also, one final thing - you don't need two parameters when calling `getItem`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8vupaa9m/1/ Avoid `id` duplicates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have problems with quotes inside quotes, I've changed  `.setItem("item"...` to `.setItem(\'item\'` and also for `getItem` and it works now

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $(document).on('click', '.btn-primary', function(){
         $('.table tbody').append('<tr class="child"><td>one</td><td><button id="re" onClick="ae(this.id); function ae(clicked_id) {var items = []; items.push(clicked_id);localStorage.setItem(\'item\',JSON.stringify(items));alert(localStorage.getItem(\'item\',JSON.stringify(items)));}" type="button" class="invite ">Invite</button></td></tr>');
      });
 });
```

Comment: Still dirty, but had the same solution as you (you got my upvote). It indeed solves his problem

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer, but you should answer with code that is good to be used. Your code (as well as the OPs) shouldn't be used in any project.

Comment: dirty yes, but the man said he has too - who are we to judge? so I tried helping him (and succeed)... my first down votes :(

Comment: I gave you a upvote. It solves the problem, and I'm sure we've all had to write code that made us feel like we needed a shower afterward. It happens.